# Get port dynamically being set in application or being run in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, port

I want to use this port for Oauth2 implementation dynamic getting the port.

Implementation:
1.Get the port running before the Oauth2 will be excuted else Oauth2 will not connect.

When application run: running port `8000` but the port capture us `8080`

```
2023-01-12 17:14:31.767  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): `8000` (http)
2023-01-12 17:14:31.777  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-12 17:14:31.777  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
System `8080`
```

Class that get the port runnig but its not getting the port 8000.
And also this Class running before Oauth2 which is good but the port is wrong 8080.

```
@Component
public class CustomContainer  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        System.out.println("System " +factory.getWebServer().getPort());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8000
```

This will work getting the port 8000 but its only being excuted after Oauth2 which it Oauth2 will failed to connect.
I already add '@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE'but wont be excuted first

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class PortDomain  implements ApplicationListener<ServletWebServerInitializedEvent> {

        private static Integer port;

        private String domain = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostName();


        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ServletWebServerInitializedEvent event) {
            setPort(event.getWebServer().getPort());
            System.out.println("Check way "+event.getWebServer().getPort());
        }

        public static void setPort(Integer port) {
            PortDomain.port = port;
        }

        public String portDomain(){
            String protocolDomain = "http://"+domain+":"+port;
            log.info("UrlUtility protocolDomain{}",protocolDomain);
            return protocolDomain;
        }


}
```

spring boot dynamically getting the port running